# Flutter Freezed Pakcage Sealed Classes Methods

Tags: flutter, freezed

When I generate sealed classes with Freezed, How can I add methods to the sealed classes?

For example:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
part 'student_state.freezed.dart';

@freezed
abstract class StudentState with _$StudentState {
  factory StudentState.loading() = StudentFetchInProgress;
  factory StudentState.success(List<int> studentIds) = StudentFetchSuccess;
}
```

I want to add a function to the StudentFetchSuccess class.
I dont know if its possible but I would appreciate even if you tell me its impossible.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: turns out freezed supports this, and there is no need to make the base type abstract.
https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/tree/master/packages/freezed#mixins-and-interfaces-for-individual-classes-for-union-types

---

Original answer - also a valid method:

I can't see an easy way. However, the `StudentFetchInProgress` and `StudentFetchSuccess` are generated as classes (e.g. for use with `is`).

So you can use extension methods to add methods to only one of the subclasses. This will only work if you cast your variable to the right type - as the method is called statically.

```
@freezed
abstract class StudentState with _$StudentState {
  factory StudentState.loading() = StudentFetchInProgress;
  factory StudentState.success(List<int> studentIds) = StudentFetchSuccess;
}

extension StudentFetchSuccessMethods on StudentFetchSuccess {
  void aMethod(){
    print("Oh Yeah!");
  }
}

void main(){
  StudentState state = StudentState.success([]);
  state.aMethod(); // this is an error and won't work
  if(state is StudentFetchSuccess){
    state.aMethod(); // smart casting makes this work
  }
}
```

If you want to add the method to all of the subclasses, the only option I can see is using freezed's `when` function. Since `StudentState` is abstract it can't have the default constructor freezed needs to add methods to the class, so this will have to be an extension too.

```
@freezed
abstract class StudentState with _$StudentState {
  factory StudentState.loading() = StudentFetchInProgress;

  factory StudentState.success(List<int> studentIds) = StudentFetchSuccess;
}

extension StudentStateMethods on StudentState {
  void aMethod() {
    when(
      loading: () => print("Still Loading"),
      success: (studentIds) => print("Loaded!"),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  StudentState state = StudentState.success([]);
  state.aMethod(); // this will dynamically call the right function
}
```